# Angular JS - ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I do not speak English very well, so I apologize in advance for my misspellings

I am creating a user administration page on a site already developed with angular js but it is the first time that i'm using it and I can not figure out the error
When I click on the list on the index.html page to be sent back to the page  amministrazione2.html where "should" start the script to get the data from the db and insert them in the table, but the video show

```
<tbody> <!-- ngRepeat: prezzo in prezzi --> <t/ body>
```

instead of my data
this is the index.html, where there is a list on the left and evry item redirect to a .html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sin...">
  <head></head>
<body>
    <div class="left_col scroll-view">
            <div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="'includes/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="modules/amministrazione2/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the header where there are the element on the left list

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

   <div class="menu_section">
     <li>
       <a href="#/amministrazione2">
          <i class="fa fa-cog infospan"></i> Amministrazione2 <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
     </li>
   </div>
</div>
```

this is the file app.js where there are the declaretions of the angular module

```
'use strict';

// declare modules
angular.module('Ammi', []);
angular.module('Amministrazione', []);
angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);
angular.module('Fornitore', []);
angular.module('Cantiere', []);
angular.module('Prezziario', []);
angular.module('Calendar', []);
angular.module('Computo', []);
angular.module('Forniture', []);
angular.module('Listino', []);
angular.module('Sal', []);



angular.module('sin...', [
    'Amministrazione',
    'Ammi',
    'Authentication',
    'Home',
    'Fornitore',
    'Cantiere',
    'Prezziario',
    'Calendar',
    'Computo',
    'Forniture',
    'Listino',
    'Sal',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'smart-table'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/amministrazione2', {
            controller: 'AmmiController',
            templateUrl:  'modules/amministrazione2/views/amministrazione2.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])
```

this is my php file for search the user information on db

```
<?php
    require_once '../includes/dbconnector.php';

    $sql = "SELECT a.id_utente, a.id_ruolo, a.nome, a.cognome, a.comune, a.indirizzo, a.cap, a.telefono1, a.telefono2, a.email, a.fax, a.note, a.user, a.password, a.calendario FROM `sal_t_utente` a ORDER BY a.id_utente";
    // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch the results into an array
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    $json = json_encode($result);

    return $json;
}
?>
```

this is the angular controller the i've create for insert and modify the data on the table

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Ammi').controller('AmmiController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$http',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.selectedPrezzo = '';

       $scope.getPrezzi = function()
       {
           $http.get('./api/amministrazione2/ricerca.php').
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.prezzi = data;
                    $scope.prezziCollection= data;
                });
       };

       $scope.editPrezzo = function(prezzo)
       {
            $scope.selectedPrezzo = prezzo;
       };

       $scope.salvaPrezzo = function(prezzo)
       {
            $http.post('./api/amministrazione2/aggiorna.php', {
                'id_utente' : prezzo.id_utente, 
                'id_ruolo' : prezzo.id_ruolo,
                'nome' : prezzo.nome,
                'cognome' : prezzo.cognome,
                'comune' : prezzo.comune, 
                'indirizzo' : prezzo.indirizzo,
                'cap' : prezzo.cap,
                'telefono1' : prezzo.telefono1, 
                'telefono2' : prezzo.telefono2,
                'email' : prezzo.email,
                'fax' : prezzo.fax, 
                'note' : prezzo.note,
                'user' : prezzo.user,
                'password' : prezzo.password,
                'calendario' : prezzo.calendario
                }
                ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.resetPrezzo();
                });
       };
       $scope.resetPrezzo = function()
       {
            $scope.getPrezzi();
            $scope.selectedPrezzo = '';
       };

       $scope.go = function ( path ) {
          $location.path( path );
        };  

    }]);
```

this is the amministrazioni2.html that show the user information

```
    <div ng-controller="getPrezzi" >
  <table st-table="prezzi" st-safe-src="prezziCollection" class="bootstrap-table table table-hover table-striped table-bordered tableBlueTh">
    <thead>
                <th>Id Utente</th>
                <th>Id Ruolo</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th >Comune</th>
                <th>Indirizzo</th>
                <th>Cap</th>
                <th >Telefono 1</th>
                <th>Telefono 2</th>
                <th >Email</th>
                <th>Fax</th>
                <th>Note</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Calendario</th>
                <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="prezzo in prezzi">
        <td>{{prezzo.id_utente}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.id_ruolo}}</td>
        <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.nome}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.nome" value="{{prezzo.nome}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.cognome}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.cognome" value="{{prezzo.cognome}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.comune}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.comune" value="{{prezzo.comune}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.indirizzo}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.indirizzo" value="{{prezzo.indirizzo}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.cap}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.cap" value="{{prezzo.cap}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.telefono1}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.telefono1" value="{{prezzo.telefono1}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.telefono2}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.telefono2" value="{{prezzo.telefono2}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.email}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.email" value="{{prezzo.email}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.fax}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.fax" value="{{prezzo.fax}}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.note}}</div>
                        <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.note" value="{{prezzo.note}}"></div>
                    </td>
        <td>{{prezzo.user}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.password}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.calendario}}</td>
        <td>
            <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">
                <button ng-click="editPrezzo(prezzo)" class="btn btn-primary">Modifica</button>
            </div>
            <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo">
                <button ng-click="salvaPrezzo(prezzo)" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                <button ng-click="resetPrezzo()" class="btn btn-danger">Annulla</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="16" class="text-center">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
```

in the end this is what i see on the site

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">


<div ng-controller="getPrezzi" class="ng-scope">
    </div><table st-table="prezzi" st-safe-src="prezziCollection" class="bootstrap-table table table-hover table-striped table-bordered tableBlueTh ng-scope">
    <thead>
                <tr><th>Id Utente</th>
                <th>Id Ruolo</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th>Comune</th>
                <th>Indirizzo</th>
                <th>Cap</th>
                <th>Telefono 1</th>
                <th>Telefono 2</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Fax</th>
                <th>Note</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Calendario</th>
                <th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: prezzo in prezzi -->

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="16" class="text-center">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7" class="ng-isolate-scope"><!-- ngIf: numPages && pages.length >= 2 --></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: First think that i noticed is that you dont have any getPrezzi controller, but AmmiController

Answer (score 0):

I add below a page functioning of the site 
to which I have referred for my page

modificaprezzario.html

```
<div ng-controller="getPrezzi" >


<table st-table="prezzi" st-safe-src="prezziCollection" class="bootstrap-table table table-hover table-striped table-bordered tableBlueTh">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="50%">
        <col width="5%">
        <col width="5%">
        <col width="5%">
        <col width="25%">
     </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ricerca globale ..." type="text"/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6" style="padding-bottom: 2em;background:#FFF"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="tariffa" class="pointer" title=Tariffa">Tariffa</th>
        <th st-sort="descrizione" class="pointer" title=Descrizione">Descrizione</th>
        <th st-sort="descrizione" class="pointer">Unit&agrave; di misura</th>
        <th st-sort="prezzo" class="pointer">Prezzo Listino</th>
        <th st-sort="prezzo_azie" class="pointer">Prezzo Aziendale</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="prezzo in prezzi">
        <td>{{prezzo.tariffa}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.descrizione}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.unita_misura}}</td>
        <td>{{prezzo.prezzo}}</td>
        <td>
            <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">{{prezzo.prezzo_azie}}</div>
            <div ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo"><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="prezzo.prezzo_azie" value="{{prezzo.prezzo_azie}}"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo != prezzo">
                <button ng-click="editPrezzo(prezzo)" class="btn btn-primary">Modifica</button>
            </div>
            <div  ng-if="selectedPrezzo == prezzo">
                <button ng-click="salvaPrezzo(prezzo)" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                <button ng-click="resetPrezzo()" class="btn btn-danger">Annulla</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="text-center">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>



</div>
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';

var myPrezziario = angular.module('Prezziario');

myPrezziario.controller('PrezziarioController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location','$http',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {

       $scope.selectedPrezzo = '';

       $scope.getPrezzi = function()
       {
            $http.get('./api/prezzario/ricerca_prezzario.php').
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.prezzi = data;
                    $scope.prezziCollection= data;
                });
       };

       $scope.editPrezzo = function(prezzo)
       {
            $scope.selectedPrezzo = prezzo;
       };

       $scope.salvaPrezzo = function(prezzo)
       {
            $http.post('./api/prezzario/aggiorna_prezzo.php', {
                'id_prezzario' : prezzo.id_prezzario, 
                'prezzo_azie' : prezzo.prezzo_azie
                }
                ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.resetPrezzo();
                });
       };

       $scope.resetPrezzo = function()
       {
            $scope.getPrezzi();
            $scope.selectedPrezzo = '';
       };

       $scope.go = function ( path ) {
          $location.path( path );
        };  

    }]);
```

ricerca_prezzario.php

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/dbconnector.php';


// a query get all the records from the users table
$sql = 'SELECT a.id_prezzario, a.tariffa, a.descrizione, a.unita_misura, a.prezzo, a.prezzo_azie  FROM sal_d_prezziario a order by a.tariffa';

// use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );

// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// fetch the results into an array
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

// convert to json
$json = json_encode( $result );

// echo the json string
echo $json;
?>
```

aggiorna_prezzo.php

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/dbconnector.php';

$sql = "update sal_d_prezziario set prezzo_azie = :prezzo_azie where id_prezzario = :id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':prezzo_azie', $data->prezzo_azie); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $data->id_prezzario); 
$stmt->execute();
?>
```